# Updating List<string> values using linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq, model-view-controller

I have a list of strings that I would like to iterate through and change the values if certain items in the list if they match up to a string value in a separate list of objects.

User inputs an email address into an Event object that contains a list of EventMembers:

```
List<string> EventMembers
```

I would then like to check through all users in the database to find the username(e-mail address) that matches with the inputted e-mail address

i understand I cannot change values in a list using a foreach loop, but i'm lost with what to do with linq. Basically i'm trying to do something like this:

```
var allUsers = _userManager.Users
                    

                foreach (var a in allUsers)
                {
                    foreach (var e in @event.EventMembers)
                    {
                        if (e == a.UserName)
                        {
                            e = a.FirstName + a.LastName;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Don't do it with LINQ, just use a `for` loop. Normal LINQ won't work as you will get "Collection Changed" exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing would be to define an initial collection of members so you don't keep modifying the list while the foreach is still running. You could then check if `EventMembers` contain the username and then replace it by accessing the value with the index.

```
var allUsers = _userManager.Users;
List<string> Members;
foreach (var a in allUsers)
{
     if (@event.EventMembers.Contains(a.UserName))
     {
         var index = @event.Members.IndexOf(a.UserName);
         Members[index] = a.FirstName + a.LastName;
     }
}
EventMembers = Members;
```

Comment: That worked. I didnt need to define an initial collection. I just used the code inside the If block and it works just fine. Thanks